# FirebaseMessagingService `builder.setContentTitle()` not working

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to receive a Android GCM push notification but the `.setContentTitle()` is not working, by default it's showing only "Notification" on the title.

here is FcmMessagingService.java

```
public class FCMMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("FCM Notification");
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
}
}
```

[but getting like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOFxu.png)

Comment: You extract `title` from the message but don't use it to build the notification.  Instead you set the notification title to "FCM Notification".  What do you want the title of the notification to be?

Comment: before I have set the `title` into `builder.setContentTitle()` but I was thiniking that maybe the problem with my `title` then just for test I set the "FCM Notification" but it's same. it's just for be sure that my `title` is ok. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the notification when app is in foreground and not in background is the result same or different

Comment: hello, not same it's working when app in foreground. what to do?

Comment: Is the onMessageReceived() method called check it or if you are testing it from firebase console then we can set the title from it may be that is overriding your notification title

Comment: no i'm sending the notification from my app server using php and i have set the service inside manifest

Comment: Since your notification is working fine when app is in foreground it means you are using notification payloads try with data payload you can check this  [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Comment: `$fields = array
(
 'to'=>$key,
 'notification'=> array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message)
);` then i tried with `$fields = array
(
 'to'=>$key,
 'data'=> array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message)
);` but same

Comment: You can check this link it has both the php and the android code [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)